# Changing Video Background

Tags: javascript

I have this code that is bringing in a video background file. 
I am trying desperately to create  multiple links that when clicked change the "filename" cloud to different file,

```
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../jquery.backgroundvideo.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var videobackground = new $.backgroundVideo($('body'), {
        "align": "centerXY",
        "width": 1280,
        "height": 720,
        "path": "media/",
        "filename": "cloud",
        "types": ["mp4","ogg","webm"]
      });
    });
  </script>
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The plugin creates a div called `#video_background`. Just remove it and call `$.backgroundVideo` again. You could put that in a function with the filename as a parameter:

```
function changeVideo(filename){
    $('#video_background').remove();

    var videobackground = new $.backgroundVideo($('body'), {
        "align": "centerXY",
        "width": 1280,
        "height": 720,
        "path": "media/",
        "filename": filename,
        "types": ["mp4","ogg","webm"]
    });
}
```

To call it by clicking on a link, you could do this:

```
<a href="#" data-video="sun">Sun video</a>
```

And

```
$('[data-video]').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the link from reloading the page
    changeVideo( $(this).attr('data-video') );
});
```

Comment: quick question, sorry im awful at JS, how do i set a default before links are clicked?

Comment: ALSO I AM SO THANKFUL FOR YOU AS A PERSON

Comment: @NicPadula  You are welcome ;) Just call `changeVideo('cloud');` directly in your _document ready_ function